# Problems using winsock2.h

Tags: c, sockets, winsock, winsock2

I have been trying for hours now but I can not figure out what the problem is with my simple client and server example using winsock2...

Here are my following two files (I tried to follow an examle from a `sys/socket.h` implementation and converting to `winsock2.h)`:

**Server:**

```
///////////  server.c  /////////////

#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

int main() {
    WSADATA wsa;
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Initialised.\n");

    char server_message[256] = "You have reached the server!";
    int server_socket;
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    printf("Listening....\n");
    listen(server_socket, 5);
    printf("Done listening\n");

    int client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL);
    printf("accepted\n");
    send(client_socket, server_message, sizeof(server_message), 0);
    closesocket(server_socket);

    return 0;
}
```

**Client:**

```
///////////  client.c  /////////////

#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

int main() {
    WSADATA wsa;
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Initialised.\n");

    int network_socket;
    network_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int connection_status = connect(network_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    printf("Connection: %d\n", connection_status);

    char server_respons[256];
    recv(network_socket, server_respons, sizeof(server_respons), 0);
    printf("The server sent the data: %s\n", server_respons);
    closesocket(network_socket);

    return 0;
}
```

I start the server first and end up with the following terminal printout:

```
Initialising Winsock...Initialised.
Listening....
Done listening
```

Indicating that it has stoped at the accept line, however when I run the client script I get the following:

```
Initialising Winsock...Initialised.
Connection: -1
The server sent the data:
```

In other words I get an error at connect() (`-1`) and the script just runs through without creating any connection? What am I doing wrong? I have tried with multiple different loops to try to connect and accept multiple times but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You have to specify the address of your server to connect instead of `INADDR_ANY` in your client code.

Comment: @MikeCAT Oh you did not have to that in `sys/socket.h`... What address do I put if I want the connection to be local on my computer?

Comment: `inet_addr("127.0.0.1")`

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks that worked, however in a Python script that im using the equivalent variables is my host name (`JV_HPEBOOK840G5`) is there a way to use the "same" name or whatever I should call it?